# How to change the SonarQube-URL from "http://localhost:9000" to something like "http://XXX:9000"?

Tags: url, sonarqube, localhost

I want to analyze Java-projects with SonarQube.

SonarQube is running on a server. I can connect to that server remotly. SonarQube is accessible on "http://localhost:9000". I want now to change that URL to something like "http://XXX:9000". I read that this is possible with the "Server base URL"-field under "Administration" --> "General Settings" in SonarQube. But it doesn't work... If I type this in my browser, then only the loading screen is shown. On "http://localhost:9000" it is still reachable. Why???
So, how can I change the URL to reach the SonarQube UI on another URL?

PS: SonarQube-Version is 7.9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to access your server locally, you can add `XXX` in your `hosts` file. Then all network requests to `XXX` will be mapped to `localhost`. But if you want to make it accessible from the internet by address `XXX` you need to register DNS and set up it to map to your server

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :)

I want to access it from the internet. Your are right. I need to make an entry in the firewall, so the "XXX" is mapped to "localhost".